# How to use Excel .SaveAs but retain original sheet name

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with Excel 2010, and have a userform which will support various processing options (i.e. sort by predefined ranges, get statistics, and the dreaded 'export' (SaveAs). I want to allow the user to export one of the sheets as either CSV or XLSX.

The issue is when I use the SaveAs to save as a CSV, it renames the sheet to the filename I selected (minus the extension).  I have searched for hours and have not found any place that provides a  solution.  I did find a Stack 5+ year old post, but it didn't have a solution (see [How to stop renaming of excelsheets after running the save macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399488/how-to-stop-renaming-of-excelsheets-after-running-the-save-macro))

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
Dim ws              As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strSaveName     As String
Dim strThisName     As String

strThisName = ThisWorkbook.Path & ThisWorkbook.Name
strSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
    fileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv")

Set ws = Worksheets("Export")
ws.SaveAs Filename:=strSaveName, FileFormat:=xlCSV

'I do the following TO UNDO THE RENAME <GROAN> (for now just saving as 0.csv)
Sheets("0").Name = "Export"  

' Then the following is to regain my original filename since I will continue working...
ws.SaveAs Filename:=strThisName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ws.Copy with no args beforehand then save the new workbook

e.g. adapt your code to be like:

```
    Dim ws              As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim strSaveName     As String

    strSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
        fileFilter:="Text Files (*.csv), *.csv")

    Set ws = Worksheets("Export")

    'Copy the ws to a new workbook
    ws.Copy
    'With the new wb:
    With Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)
        'Save and close the new workbook
        .SaveAs Filename:=strSaveName, FileFormat:=xlCSV
        .Close False
    End With
```

p.s. I assume you have code to handle clicking Cancel on GetSaveAsFilename and just removed it for clarity in the question ;)

Comment: Yes, I just didn't show the code for the 'Cancel'.  I added a '.Saved = True' to your code to avoid the 'Do you want to save...' when the '.Close' was issued.  Thank you very much for your solution!!!

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn ah, I didn't think that would show as there were no new changes since the last save but I must be wrong in this situation (all a bit funny with new workbooks). Glad it helped.

Comment: I was also surprised for the prompt as I agree - it was just saved!